# Logstash input s3 filename inside S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, logstash

I want to send input to logstash a specific file which is uploaded in S3.

I have an S3 bucket, and want to specify the file name so that only that particular S3 file name can be picked up as an input to the Elasticsearch and not the contents of the entire bucket.

Any idea how this can be done. Tried to give the file name but didnt work.

I also have not been able to find similar questions.

Edit.. Here is the input of the conf file which I am using.

input 
{

```
  s3 
{
    bucket => "logstashtestbucket1"
    access_key_id => "Key"
    secret_access_key => "SecretKey"
    region => "us-west-2"
}
```

}

Comment: Please show your input config and the filename you used.

Comment: Did you find an answer? I have a similar problem: https://serverfault.com/questions/873840/elasticsearch-amazon-s3-plugin-config

Answer (score 0):

When you only want to load one object from s3 using logstash, then specify [`prefix`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-s3.html#plugins-inputs-s3-prefix) with the entire path to the object in it.

If your file is logstashtestbucket1 and your objects have the paths "a/b/c.txt" and "a/b/d.txt" and you only want to load "a/b/c.txt" then your logstash input would read:

```
input {
  s3 
  {
    bucket => "logstashtestbucket1"
    prefix => "a/b/c.txt"
    region => "us-west-2"
    watch_for_new_files => false
  }
}
```

`watch_for_new_files` needs to be set to tell logstash to load the object which is already there and then exit.  Otherwise it will wait for a new object to arrive with that prefix, and therefore never exit or do any work.

Tested with logstash 7.6, `prefix` has been a feature since at least logstash 2.x.

I took the secrets out of the config block in case anyone copies this reference without understanding it.  Please put your secrets in environment variables, if you're not running an EC2 with permissions in its [instance profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html).